# Meaning of “leb dich aus”

Tags: meaning, english-to-german, idiom

I wanted to say something like “live out loud”, to express the idea of living fast and wild.

A German woman told me the sentence “leb dich aus”.

Is it correct? What does “dich aus” mean?

Answer (score 1):

> Leb dich aus.

*Act out yourself.*

The core of that command is the verb **ausleben** — *to act out*, *to live out*, *to enjoy life*. Its a separable verb, so it becomes *Leb … aus.* in that sentence. *Dich* simply is the accusative of *du*, here it means *yourself*.

The very idea behind that short sentence above is the analogy to

> Leer dich aus.

*Empty yourself.*

A more common command would be:

> Leb **deine Träume** aus.

*Act out **your dreams**.*

Comment: I've never heard someone use "Leer dich aus". That sounds wrong.

Comment: It's only an *analogy*.

Comment: You just use it as an example how to form an imperative with an reflexive verb?

Comment: I use it as an analogy to *let it out*.

Comment: *Let it out* is translated to *lass es raus*.... I honestly don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

[Sich ausleben](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausleben) bedeutet das

> Leben ohne Einschränkung genießen, auskosten; ungebunden leben; sich [ungehemmt] ausleben

Example:

> Du willst dich ausleben? You want to enjoy life to the fullest?
>
> Leb dich aus! Enjoy life to the fullest!